# How do I set up email alerts for 500 errors using Flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I am using flask, marshmallow, and sql alchemy to make an API. I want to configure email alerts on 500 errors. The other error types I have the email alerts for work fine.

Error Handling Code

```
@app.errorhandler(ValidationError)
def handle_marshmallow_validation(err):  # except ValidationError as err
    return jsonify(err.messages), 400

@app.errorhandler(500)
def server_error(e):
    if e == 500:
        error_500_email()
```

Function called in the 500 error handler:

```
def error_500_email():
    s = smtplib.SMTP(host='mailo2.uhc.com', port=25)
    text = "There was an error"
    msg = MIMEText(str(text))
    msg['Subject'] = 'Prod SA Tool Error'
    s.sendmail('sa_prod@optum.com', 'ian.christ@optum.com', msg.as_string())
    s.quit()
```

Comment: This is not related to marshmallow. But as a sidenote, I would return a 422 on marshmallow error. Consider using webargs to do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the `e == 500` condition always evaluates to `False` even in case of 500 error.

You could fix it, but why not remove it? What's the purpose of this test if you decorate the handler with `@app.errorhandler(500)`?